# How do you force a win in 4x4x4 TicTacToe

Tags: strategy, game, tic-tac-toe

I have read in the wikipedia page of TicTacToe that it is possible for the first player to force a win in a 4x4x4 board. I tried to find a strategy on how to do it online but failed. So, how do you force a win as first player in 4x4x4 TicTacToe?

Comment: The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_tic-tac-toe#cite_note-7) links to a [qubic dictionary](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6pbHEZND52eMzlzWWRCWFdrTm8/edit), and this turns out to be a text file containing a list of moves for perfect play that Oren Patashnik found in 1980. I don't think there is an easy to memorize strategy.

Comment: So I guess it is still a pretty fair game because memorizing all the moves would be quite hard? I am trying to figure out if I should include this game in a small tournament, that's why I am asking.

Comment: I don't think the existence of a winning strategy matters if it is hard to exploit by humans. Like normal tic tac toe there may be a significant first player advantage regardless of a winning strategy, and that would need to be compensated for, for example by always playing an even number of games between two players, letting both players go first the same number of times.

Comment: Try this book: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689613?seq=1